# Can we override an file from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I know, in Jenkins we can overwrite property variables in the Jenkins. I would like to know if there is a way we can override a file  from the Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

The [custom config file provider](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040961031-How-to-use-a-custom-config-file-provider) lets you store a file in the custom config areas and during build time you can read that content and place it in a file wherever you want.

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "${jenkinsFileID}", targetLocation: "${destinationFile}")]) {
            echo "Copied ${jenkinsFileID} content to file ${destinationFile}"
}
```